# Java SSLSocket write SocketException after new connection

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, connection, imap

Here is my code:

```
            Socket s = server.accept();
            s.setSoTimeout(1000);
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            out.flush();
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            System.out.println(s.isClosed());
            out.write(("* OK " + ((String)host.getConfig().get("domain")).split(",")[0] + " IMAP ready." + crlf).getBytes());
            out.flush();
            host.addWorkIMAP(s, in, out, server instanceof SSLServerSocket);
```

Which on the line that writes the string, I get `java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed`.

(The server is a SSLServerSocket).

I know for a fact that the socket is NOT closed, as the call to isClosed() returns false. Furthermore, Thunderbird is timing out after I get this error(I'm writing a IMAP server).

Stack Trace:

```
[12:54:54] java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:422)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:460)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:863)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.waitForClose(SSLSocketImpl.java:1571)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.HandshakeOutStream.flush(HandshakeOutStream.java:103)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.sendChangeCipherSpec(Handshaker.java:689)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ServerHandshaker.sendChangeCipherAndFinish(ServerHandshaker.java:1279)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ServerHandshaker.clientFinished(ServerHandshaker.java:1239)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ServerHandshaker.processMessage(ServerHandshaker.java:225)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:593)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:529)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:943)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1188)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:654)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:100)
at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:90)
at java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(FilterOutputStream.java:80)
at mail.smtp.ThreadAcceptSMTP.run(ThreadAcceptSMTP.java:65)
```

Comment: Stack trace please. Evidently the exception happens inside the `host.getConfig()` method, which you haven't posted either. `Socket.isClosed()` only tells you whether *you* have closed the socket, not whether the *peer* has closed the *connection.*

Comment: @EJP That function is safe, it's not going to throw a SocketException(or any, It's called a lot elsewhere) I'll post the whole stacktrace, but I don't think it gives much relevant detail.

Comment: Well there is no `write()` in the code you posted, so suspicion initially has to fall on code that it calls. If that code is exempt, where is the exception being thrown from?

Comment: @EJP Line 7 is `write()`, in the code I posted above. I did some further testing, the exception can be thrown earlier by calling `((SSLSocket)s).startHandshake();`, which shows an identical stacktrace. As far as I can tell, the issue has to do with Java trying to change the cipher suite for some reason?